# Extending the functionality of an Activity from a referenced library project

Tags: android, maven

I'm developing tab base android application using maven-android-plugin, i need to share the same code base and resources to several applications, so what i did was make the project as library project and reference it to other projects.

Ref:http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib

Now i need to add more functionality to the activities.so what i did copy the activity from  library project and put into the reference project with the same package name,When i run the build i'm getting "duplicate class error",for resources this work fine.

how can i add more functionality to activity (coming from library project)

sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could think of the following:

- Subclass the Activity that you want to extend the functionality of.
- Extract the functionality from the original Activity into classes (probably in the form of utility class) and use that in your new Activity
- If this extra functionality is reacting to a particular event that you need to handle, consider extracting the listener in your activity so that you could extend the functionality by setting the listener that conform to a specific Interface from outside your activity

Comment: i thought about extending the activity but if i did i have to change the whole lot of classes by extending,so i gave up that, i was looking something if the same activity  exist in the project ignore the library class activity and use the project activity. is it possible with maven build please advise

Comment: I haven't tried anything like that. Seems to be dangerous way of doing it. I'll check if I come across anything that could do what you want